# Is there a function to find an expression and return the element ahead?

Tags: javascript

Good morning,

I would like to know if there is a specific function in javascript, which extracts from the message below only the value "**141**", after identifying the term "Temperatura.SaidaATM".

```
{ "d" : { "Temperature.ATM Output" : [141]
```

**Edit: The above package comes from sub MQTT in Json format.

The complete package is this below:

{"d":{"Temperature.ATM Output":[141]},"ts":"2021-12-18T13:28:34.964579"}

However I need to treat it to extract only the information between brackets "[xxx]", in the example above it is "141" but this value varies.

But I also need the quoted reference "Temperature.OutputATM".

Summing up:
1- The message "{"d":{"Temperature.OutputATM":[xxx]}"ts":"2021-12-18T13:28:34.964579"}" is received.

2- I need to extract the xxx from a javascript code

3- When reading "Temperatura.SaidaATM" in the message, return only what is in square brackets right after "[xxx]"

4- Final message return: xxx

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, there is no such built-in functionality. If you explain what you actually want to do, we can probably help you more.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript, as written. Also, how does `Temperatura.SaidaATM` related to `Temperature.ATM Output`?

Comment: It is an object and you reference the property and then the array. Do you only have a partial key? What is your exact problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: This looks like JSON. Parse it and use dot and bracket notation to find what you need.

Comment: I edited the question to improve understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You have an object and you can select by key like that:

```js
data = { "d" : { "Temperature.ATM Output" : [141] }}

console.log(data.d["Temperature.ATM Output"][0])
```

Comment: I edited the question to improve understanding. Thanks